# Cannot use downloaded library (pdfmake) offline

Tags: javascript, offline, pdfmake

I am trying to use pdfmake JS library in an offline webpage.
I downloaded the CDN file from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/pdfmake.min.js and saved it offline in ..app/js/pdfmake.js

I loaded the library using require:

```
require([
   'js/pdfmake.js',
...])
```

I  test the library using the example below:

```
var buttonTS = document.getElementById("buttonTS")
butonTS.addEventListener("click", function(){
            
  var docDefinition = {
    content: [
            'First paragraph',
            'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
        ]
    };

    var now = new Date();

    var pdf = pdfmake.createPdf(docDefinition);
    pdf.write('pdfs/basics.pdf').then(() => {
        console.log(new Date() - now);
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

But the library does not load, and throws the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pdfmake is not defined
```

This is odd because I have other libraries (SweetAlert), which work with no problems.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `pdfmake.createPdf(docDefinition);` Where do you instantiate `pdfmake`? Not familliar with that library, but I assume you need to instantiate an object to work with first.

Comment: I don't need to instantiate pdfmake. It should work as a module and give me access to all functions. This is how I use other libraries as well. I am testing this example: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/examples/basics.js

Comment: Ah. Well look at the example code and at your code. The example: `var pdfmake = require('..` VS your code `require([...`

Comment: I instantiated the library as you suggested, but now it says `Uncaught TypeError: pdf.write is not a function`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a working example you can check

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/pdfmake.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-a9NgEEK7tsCvABL7KqtUTQjl69z7091EVPpw5KxPlZ93T141ffe1woLtbXTX+r2/8TtTvRX/v4zTL2UlMUPgwg=="
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/vfs_fonts.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-P0bOMePRS378NwmPDVPU455C/TuxDS+8QwJozdc7PGgN8kLqR4ems0U/3DeJkmiE31749vYWHvBOtR+37qDCZQ=="
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script> -->

<script src="./pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vfs_fonts.min.js"></script>

<script>
  const docDefinition = {
    pageSize: 'A4',
    pageOrientation: 'landscape',
    content: [
      'Hey, it works'
    ],
    pageMargins: [20, 5, 10, 5],
    info: {
      title: 'Some PDF Name',
      author: 'Author Name',
    },
    defaultStyle: {
      fontSize: 9,
      bold: false,
    }
  }

  const pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
  pdf.open({});
</script>

</html>
```

If loads the libs downloaded from the cdn. I have also kept the actual cdn links in comment.

The code here is writted directly inside the html file inside a script tag. If you want to keep your code in seperate js files, make sure the script tags for those files are kept after the libs

```html
<script src="./pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vfs_fonts.min.js"></script>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

In these examples, I am using pdfmake on client side (browser). You can get the docs for client side usage [here](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/client-side/)

However, if you are generating your pdfs on the backend, [these](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/server-side/) docs might help you better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).